# VueJS getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when I delete and add an Sensor information

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, undefined, typeerror

I am trying to create `sensorArray` dynamically in my VueJS application. For this when I create an element and delete it and then when I try to create a new one then I get the following error:

```
client.js:227 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at eval (templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./pages/Test.vue?vue&type=template&id=cde3d4aa&:44)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.runtime.esm.js:2643)
```

Following is the simple Vuejs application I have:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span>Sensor Information : </span>
    <button class="btn btn-info" @click="addSensorInfo($event)">
      Add Sensor
    </button>
    <br>
    <span v-if="sensorArray.length > 0"><b>Sensor Element: </b></span>
    <span v-if="sensorArray.length > 0">&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div v-for="sensor in sensorArray" :key="sensor.ID" class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label">Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input v-model="sensorArray[sensor.ID].value" type="text" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteSensorInfo($event,sensor.ID)"><i class="bi bi-trash" /></button>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sensorID: 0,
      sensorArray: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addSensorInfo (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      const sensor = {}
      sensor.ID = this.sensorID
      this.sensorArray.push(sensor)
      this.sensorID++
    },
    deleteSensorInfo (event, sensorID) {
      event.preventDefault()
      this.sensorArray.splice(this.sensorArray.filter(obj => obj.ID === sensorID), 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

1. Click on `Add Sensor` button: A text field and delete button will appear.
2. Click on `Delete ICON` and delete the field.
3. Now again click on `Add Sensor` then I get following error:

```
client.js:227 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

Since I have a lot of elements within my `SensorArray` I am not creating the dedicated element and trying to create everything dynamically based on user click. Can someone please let me know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You could use `.prevent` modifier as shown here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on You are also probably in this case: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays Did you checked what you do have in your Vue devtools after the delete?

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your response. You mean `event.preventDefault()` right? If so then I am already using it and still getting errors. Can you please suggest me something?

Comment: Just recommended a small improvement here. It will not fix the other issues. Did you checked your Vue devtools? What is the current state after the deletion?

Comment: @kissu After the delete operation my `sensorArray` becomes `sensorArray:Array[0]` and `sensorID:1` so basically that added element has been removed during the `delete`operation. Now, when I try to add again then i get the error.

Comment: Where is the issue located actually? Is it `this.sensorID++` or with the `this.sensorArray.push(sensor)`? Maybe try `this.sensorID += 1` here. Otherwise, I guess that a [repro] could be helpful here!

Comment: @kissu The problem is coming when I try to delete an added element and then try to add a new element again. Actually, I have tried to create a very basic example in the above-provided code. I have taken a chunk from my application and created a small single-page application to re-create the scenario and issue. If you add a `page` to any of your `Vue-js` applications and paste the following code then it should work and you should be able to recreate the issue I am facing. Thanks for your response. Looking forward to some suggestion.

Comment: @kissu The problem was actually the way I am accessing the element within my `HTML Template`. The solution provided below worked for me. Thanks for your time and response. The issue has been resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Error

This is not a valid JavaScript operation

```
this.sensorArray.splice(this.sensorArray.filter(obj => obj.ID === sensorID), 1)
```

[Splice signature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?retiredLocale=it) expects a number at first position

```
splice(start: number, deleteCount: number)
```

[Filter signature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=it) returns an array.

##### Solution

```
const idx = this.sensorArray.findIndex(obj => obj.ID === sensorID);
if (idx !== -1) {
    this.sensorArray.splice(idx, 1)
}
```

Or as mentioned you can use a more concise form

```
this.sensorArray = this.sensorArray.filter(obj => obj.ID === sensorID);
```

### Second Error

Now I noticed that you are performing a strange array access. An array is indexed by `id` not by your custom `sensor.ID`, so this `sensorArray[sensor.ID].value` makes no sense. It works before a delete by pure chance (due to how you are generating IDs).

This should be your code (note the `v-model="sensor.value"`):

```
<div v-for="sensor in sensorArray" :key="sensor.ID" class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input v-model="sensor.value" type="text" class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteSensorInfo($event,sensor.ID)"><i class="bi bi-trash" /></button>
</div>
```

Furthermore `.value` is never set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I tried the solution mentioned here. It will delete the added `sensorInfo` but when I click on `Add sensor` again then I am getting the same error : `client.js:227 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`. Its not working as expected. Can you please suggest how to fix it?

Comment: I tried many things it not happening because of `splice` method because after performing the operating I am getting my `sensorArray` as empty but when I click on `Add Sensor` again then I get the error so its not happening because of `Delete` I believe. Can you please suggest me some work-arounds?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and response. Your latest suggestion and fix worked for me. Accepting the answer and proving the upvote. Thanks again. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and `filter`, to delete the item.
Simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
this.sensorArray = this.sensorArray.filter(obj => obj.ID === sensorID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not deleting the element from my `sensorArray`. Can you suggest how to delete element from Array and avoid the error `client.js:227 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`

Comment: I tried many things it not happening because of `splice` method because after performing the operating I am getting my `sensorArray` as empty but when I click on `Add Sensor` again then I get the error so its not happening because of `Delete` I believe. Can you please suggest me some work-arounds?